# Android Maven TaskStackBuilder cannot find symbol

Tags: android, maven

I'm trying to solve this error: "cannot find symbol" with the class *TaskStackBuilder*. I use Travis-ci and have this problem too: https://travis-ci.org/melchor629/Musicote-Melchor629
and the error of the code, that aims maven, is:

```
    int mID = 1;

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.altavoz)
            .setContentTitle("Musicote")
            .setContentText("Reproduciendo "+titulo+" de "+artista)
            ;//TODO poner que sea fijo

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(mID, notification.build());
```

And i haven't any idea to solve this, I tried all I know :S I'm using "android.support.v4.TaskStackBuilder"

Comment: This could be a dependency with the wrong scope...  Can you show the output of a run of `mvn -X package`?

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/melchor629/Musicote-Melchor629/builds/5790460 with mvm -X package

Comment: What is the code at `/home/travis/build/melchor629/Musicote-Melchor629/src/com/melchor629/musicote/Reproductor.java:[97,56]` and `/home/travis/build/melchor629/Musicote-Melchor629/src/com/melchor629/musicote/Reproductor.java:[103,35]`?  Also, what does your pom look like?

Comment: This code is in the post ^ and the pom likes: [pom.xml](https://github.com/melchor629/Musicote-Melchor629/blob/master/pom.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the v4 support library? If so, are you importing the correct TaskStackBuilder (   android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder)?